# Uploading a file with ASIFormDataRequest does not work

Tags: iphone, file-upload, upload, asihttprequest

I am using the ASIHTTPRequest framework trying to upload a file to my websever via iPhone.
Below is the code. As long as I don't use the setFile method, I get a 200 back from the server, so everthing is fine. As soon as I implement setFile, the server returns 0. I would expect a 401 or anything like this, as I could imagine that I deal with an authentication issue. 
My server is an IIS, why I use the NTLM way in the request. Do I miss something?

```
NSInteger httpStatus;
NSString *httpResponseString;
NSError *httpRequestError;

NSArray *paths = [[[NSArray alloc] init] autorelease];
paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abiliator_basis_de_ar.xml"];


NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://my.url.com/"]; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:NO];
[request setUsername:@"myUserName"];
[request setPassword:@"myPassword"];
[request setDomain:@"myDomainName"];
[request setFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filename] forKey:@"xml"];
[request startSynchronous];
httpRequestError = [request error];
httpResponseString = [request responseString];
httpStatus = [request responseStatusCode];
if (!httpRequestError) {
    httpStatus = [request responseStatusCode];
    NSLog(@"Class %@, Method: %@ - OK login and filetransfer successful '%i'", self.myClassName, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), httpStatus);
} 
else {            
    NSLog(@"Class %@, Method: %@ - Error '%i' occurred sending the http request", self.myClassName, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), httpStatus);
}
```

Yes the file exists, here the result from the ls:

```
rene-stegs-macbook-pro:~ renesteg$ ls -ltr '/Users/renesteg/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/417BD791-64BC-48D0-B519-F10C7F617E36/Documents/abiliator_basis_de_ar.xml'
-rw-r--r--@ 1 renesteg  staff  1062 22 Mai 13:44 /Users/renesteg/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/417BD791-64BC-48D0-B519-F10C7F617E36/Documents/abiliator_basis_de_ar.xml
```

And here the value of filename:

```
Filename string is: '/Users/renesteg/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/417BD791-64BC-48D0-B519-F10C7F617E36/Documents/abiliator_basis_de_ar.xml
```

Comment: Thx, meccan. see the edit of my post.

Comment: is the [NSURL URLWithString:filename] also a valid object or nil?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong while uploading file.

it need to like this

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:120];

    [request setPostFormat:ASIMultipartFormDataPostFormat];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"multipart/form-data"];  
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == YES) {

        [request setFile:filePath withFileName:@"test.xml" andContentType:@"xml" forKey:@"FieldName"];
    }
```

Here file path need to set for fromdata request.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error. Good practice to check for the file existence, would have included that anyway. The rest though is not much different of what I coded. I still believe that I have to configure something on the server and that the code is actually ok.

Comment: i have set file testing if not exist file but also i have changed method whatever you are using before. Just conform with your PHP developer that you are using correct parameters for uploading...

i have changed my answer i hope now it will works...

Comment: Neel, I think you just mentioned the key: PHP. That seems to be missing. I actually have a PHP code which would copy the file to the correct directory. Do you know, what I need to call that PHP file or where I map it?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try usingsetData:forKey: and send the data of the xml file, example below..

```
.....
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://my.url.com/"]; 
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[request setShouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge:NO];
[request setUsername:@"myUserName"];
[request setPassword:@"myPassword"];
[request setDomain:@"myDomainName"];
[request setData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileName] forKey:@"xml"];
[request startSynchronous];
.....
```

Also, you should probably make this an `asynchronous` request.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error occurs because you should use:

```
[request setFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename] forKey:@"xml"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was between the line of Neels comment: missing PHP. 
And this of course needs to be called in the URL, so the correct way to build the URL is:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://my.url.com/upload.php"];
```

This way I got the mapping my iPhone httpRequest code and the PHP.

Here's the required PHP code:

```
     <?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['xml']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['xml']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['xml']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
    echo "Error uploading". basename( $_FILES['xml']['name']). " occured";
 }
 ?>
```